# Iot Hub module "Modbus" looks healthy and well parametrized but no data received

Tags: azure-iot-hub, hyper-v, azure-iot-edge, modbus-tcp, azure-iot-hub-device-management

### I am connecting a "Janitza UMG96RM-E" device to a Windows Laptop where I am using Hyper-V to use Linux cmds. I registered the Laptop as an Edge device and added Modbus to the set of modules. I read the Janitza documentation (start Address, nbre of bits ...) and I Added the correct Ip Address the Module Twins file... Everything looks heathy except I am not receiving any data from the Modbus module... I am not able to figure out what is wrong ? Here is some logs from edgeHub module.

```
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:01.503 +00:00 [INF] - Add node: myEdgeDevice/DefenderIotMicroAgent
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:01.711 +00:00 [INF] - Add node: myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:01.868 +00:00 [INF] - Done refreshing device scope identities cache. Waiting for 60 minutes.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:01.956 +00:00 [INF] - Obtained edge hub config from module twin
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.377 +00:00 [INF] - Set the following 1 route(s) in edge hub
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.377 +00:00 [INF] - modbusToIoTHub: FROM /messages/modules/Modbus/outputs/modbusOutput INTO $upstream
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.378 +00:00 [INF] - Updated message store TTL to 7200 seconds
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.379 +00:00 [INF] - Updated the edge hub store and forward configuration
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.391 +00:00 [INF] - Started operation Get EdgeHub config
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.395 +00:00 [INF] - Initialized edge hub configuration
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.397 +00:00 [INF] - Starting protocol heads - (MQTT, AMQP, HTTP)
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.410 +00:00 [INF] - Starting MQTT head
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.524 +00:00 [INF] - Initializing TLS endpoint on port 8883 for MQTT head.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.845 +00:00 [INF] - Starting AMQP head
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:02.873 +00:00 [INF] - Started MQTT head
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:03.251 +00:00 [INF] - Started AMQP head
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:03.255 +00:00 [INF] - Starting HTTP head
<4> 2022-03-08 18:32:04.026 +00:00 [WRN] - Overriding address(es) '"http://+:80"'. Binding to endpoints defined in "UseKestrel()" instead.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:04.063 +00:00 [INF] - Started HTTP head
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.529 +00:00 [INF] - New token received on the Cbs link
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.727 +00:00 [INF] - Client myEdgeDevice/Modbus in device scope authenticated locally.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.745 +00:00 [INF] - New device connection for device myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.746 +00:00 [INF] - Client myEdgeDevice/Modbus connected to edgeHub, processing existing subscriptions.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.750 +00:00 [INF] - Attempting to connect to IoT Hub for client myEdgeDevice/Modbus via AMQP...
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.767 +00:00 [INF] - Bind device proxy for device myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.767 +00:00 [INF] - Initialized device listener in the AMQP protocol head for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.786 +00:00 [INF] - Opened link Events for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.827 +00:00 [INF] - Cloud connection for myEdgeDevice/Modbus is True
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.827 +00:00 [INF] - Connection status for myEdgeDevice/Modbus changed to ConnectionEstablished
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.827 +00:00 [INF] - Client myEdgeDevice/Modbus connected to cloud, processing existing subscriptions.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.827 +00:00 [INF] - Skipping myEdgeDevice/Modbus for subscription processing, as it is currently being processed.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.827 +00:00 [INF] - Created cloud proxy for client myEdgeDevice/Modbus via AMQP, with client operation timeout 20 seconds.
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.828 +00:00 [INF] - Initialized cloud proxy 9450b673-5293-4c0b-830f-5c564f317321 for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:05.828 +00:00 [INF] - Created cloud connection for client myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:06.116 +00:00 [INF] - Opened link TwinReceiving for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:06.126 +00:00 [INF] - Processing pending subscriptions for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:06.129 +00:00 [INF] - Opened link TwinSending for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:06.659 +00:00 [INF] - Processing pending subscriptions for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:06.661 +00:00 [INF] - Opened link ModuleMessages for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:06.760 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties for myEdgeDevice/$edgeHub
<6> 2022-03-08 18:32:12.133 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 18:36:56.469 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 18:41:56.461 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 18:46:56.461 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 18:51:56.464 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 18:56:56.464 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:01:53.016 +00:00 [INF] - Started task to cleanup processed and stale messages for endpoint iothub
<6> 2022-03-08 19:01:53.083 +00:00 [INF] - Cleaned up 0 messages from queue for endpoint iothub and 0 messages from message store.
<6> 2022-03-08 19:01:56.460 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:06:56.460 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:11:56.463 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:16:56.463 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:21:56.463 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:26:56.464 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:30:05.794 +00:00 [INF] - New token received on the Cbs link
<6> 2022-03-08 19:30:05.800 +00:00 [INF] - Token updated for myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 19:30:57.126 +00:00 [INF] - Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://172.18.0.3:9600/metrics
<6> 2022-03-08 19:30:57.203 +00:00 [INF] - Request finished in 76.276ms 200 text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8
<6> 2022-03-08 19:31:53.089 +00:00 [INF] - Started task to cleanup processed and stale messages for endpoint iothub
<6> 2022-03-08 19:31:53.157 +00:00 [INF] - Cleaned up 0 messages from queue for endpoint iothub and 0 messages from message store.
<6> 2022-03-08 19:31:56.459 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:01.877 +00:00 [INF] - Starting refresh of device scope identities cache
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:02.390 +00:00 [INF] - Starting periodic operation Get EdgeHub config...
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:02.781 +00:00 [INF] - Obtained edge hub config from module twin
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:02.939 +00:00 [INF] - Set the following 1 route(s) in edge hub
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:02.940 +00:00 [INF] - modbusToIoTHub: FROM /messages/modules/Modbus/outputs/modbusOutput INTO $upstream
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:02.941 +00:00 [INF] - Updated message store TTL to 7200 seconds
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:02.941 +00:00 [INF] - Updated the edge hub store and forward configuration
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:02.941 +00:00 [INF] - Successfully completed periodic operation Get EdgeHub config
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:03.056 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties for myEdgeDevice/$edgeHub
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:04.404 +00:00 [INF] - Not changed node: myEdgeDevice
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:04.405 +00:00 [INF] - Not changed node: myEdgeDevice/$edgeAgent
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:04.405 +00:00 [INF] - Not changed node: myEdgeDevice/$edgeHub
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:04.405 +00:00 [INF] - Not changed node: myEdgeDevice/DefenderIotMicroAgent
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:04.406 +00:00 [INF] - Not changed node: myEdgeDevice/Modbus
<6> 2022-03-08 19:32:04.406 +00:00 [INF] - Done refreshing device scope identities cache. Waiting for 60 minutes.
<6> 2022-03-08 19:36:56.459 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:41:56.461 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:46:56.462 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:51:56.460 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 19:56:56.460 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 20:01:53.157 +00:00 [INF] - Started task to cleanup processed and stale messages for endpoint iothub
<6> 2022-03-08 20:01:53.159 +00:00 [INF] - Cleaned up 0 messages from queue for endpoint iothub and 0 messages from message store.
<6> 2022-03-08 20:01:56.463 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 20:06:56.461 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 20:11:56.460 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 20:16:56.463 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
<6> 2022-03-08 20:21:56.461 +00:00 [INF] - Entering periodic task to reauthenticate connected clients
```

---

**Modbus Module Twin:**

```
{
    "deviceId": "myEdgeDevice",
    "moduleId": "Modbus",
    "etag": "AAAAAAAAAA4=",
    "deviceEtag": "Mzc5OTQzNzE5",
    "status": "enabled",
    "statusUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "connectionState": "Connected",
    "lastActivityTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "cloudToDeviceMessageCount": 0,
    "authenticationType": "sas",
    "x509Thumbprint": {
        "primaryThumbprint": null,
        "secondaryThumbprint": null
    },
    "modelId": "",
    "version": 33,
    "properties": {
        "desired": {
            "PublishInterval": 2000,
            "SlaveConfigs": {
                "Slave01": {
                    "SlaveConnection": "192.168.151.50",
                    "HwId": "HwId1",
                    "Operations": {
                        "Op01": {
                            "PollingInterval": "100",
                            "UnitId": "1",
                            "StartAddress": "19000",
                            "Count": "32",
                            "DisplayName": "Voltage",
                            "CorrelationId": "MessageType1"
                        }
                    },
                    "TcpPort": "502",
                    "RetryCount": "10",
                    "RetryInterval": "100"
                }
            },
            "routes": {
                "modbusToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/Modbus/outputs/modbusOutput INTO $upstream"
            },
            "$metadata": {
                "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14,
                "PublishInterval": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                },
                "SlaveConfigs": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14,
                    "Slave01": {
                        "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                        "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14,
                        "SlaveConnection": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                        },
                        "HwId": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                        },
                        "Operations": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14,
                            "Op01": {
                                "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                                "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14,
                                "PollingInterval": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                                },
                                "UnitId": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                                },
                                "StartAddress": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                                },
                                "Count": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                                },
                                "DisplayName": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                                },
                                "CorrelationId": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "TcpPort": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                        },
                        "RetryCount": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                        },
                        "RetryInterval": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                        }
                    }
                },
                "routes": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                    "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14,
                    "modbusToIoTHub": {
                        "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:30:17.436628Z",
                        "$lastUpdatedVersion": 14
                    }
                }
            },
            "$version": 14
        },
        "reported": {
            "PublishInterval": 2000,
            "SlaveConfigs": {
                "Slave01": {
                    "Operations": {
                        "Op01": {
                            "PollingInterval": 100,
                            "UnitId": 1,
                            "StartAddress": "19000",
                            "Count": 32,
                            "DisplayName": "Voltage",
                            "CorrelationId": "MessageType1"
                        }
                    },
                    "SlaveConnection": "192.168.151.50",
                    "RetryCount": 10,
                    "RetryInterval": 100,
                    "TcpPort": 502,
                    "HwId": "HwId1"
                }
            },
            "$metadata": {
                "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z",
                "PublishInterval": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                },
                "SlaveConfigs": {
                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z",
                    "Slave01": {
                        "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z",
                        "Operations": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z",
                            "Op01": {
                                "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z",
                                "PollingInterval": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                                },
                                "UnitId": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                                },
                                "StartAddress": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                                },
                                "Count": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                                },
                                "DisplayName": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                                },
                                "CorrelationId": {
                                    "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "SlaveConnection": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                        },
                        "RetryCount": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                        },
                        "RetryInterval": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                        },
                        "TcpPort": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                        },
                        "HwId": {
                            "$lastUpdated": "2022-03-08T18:32:11.9932421Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "$version": 19
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the info that I used from the Janitza docs to configure the Module Twin:
[Modbus address list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPTU5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the problem was the register start-address that I am reading from.
In my case I had the add a 4 in the beginning (Holding Register) and +1 in the end.
example: if in the documentation of the slave device I can read the Power from the address 19000 : in the Modbus Module twin I specify the address to be 419001 !
I hope this can help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the logs of the module? Check the name of the module with iotedge list.

```
sudo iotedge list
sudo iotedge logs Modbus
```

You need to specify a [route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2020-11) from the modbus module to the $upstream channel of edgeHub to have the data routed to Azure IoT Hub that matches the name of the module from the deployment manifest. It looks correct, but doublechek won't hurt.

To see the data going through the IoT Hub, you can use the [Azure IoT explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/howto-use-iot-explorer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the Modbus logs shows the following:
` IoT Hub module client initialized.
Desired property change: 
{"PublishInterval":2000,"SlaveConfigs":{"Slave01":{"SlaveConnection":"192.168.151.50","HwId":"HwId1","Operations":{"Op01":{"PollingInterval":"100","UnitId":"1","StartAddress":"19000","Count":"32","DisplayName":"Voltage","CorrelationId":"MessageType1"}},"TcpPort":"502","RetryCount":"10","RetryInterval":"100"}},"routes":{"modbusToIoTHub":"FROM `

Comment: /messages/modules/Modbus/outputs/modbusOutput INTO $upstream"},"$version":14}
Attempt to load configuration: {"PublishInterval":2000,"SlaveConfigs":{"Slave01":{"SlaveConnection":"192.168.151.50","HwId":"HwId1","Operations":{"Op01":{"PollingInterval":"100","UnitId":"1","StartAddress":"19000","Count":"32","DisplayName":"Voltage","CorrelationId":"MessageType1"}},"TcpPort":"502","RetryCount":"10","RetryInterval":"100"}}

Comment: ,"routes":{"modbusToIoTHub":"FROM /messages/modules/Modbus/outputs/modbusOutput INTO $upstream"},"$version":14}

Comment: Saving reported properties: {"PublishInterval":2000,"SlaveConfigs":{"Slave01":{"Operations":{"Op01":{"PollingInterval":100,"UnitId":1,"StartAddress":"19000","Count":32,"DisplayName":"Voltage","CorrelationId":"MessageType1"}},

Comment: "SlaveConnection":"192.168.151.50","RetryCount":10,"RetryInterval":100,"TcpPort":502,"HwId":"HwId1","BaudRate":null,"StopBits":null,"DataBits":null,"Parity":null}}}

Comment: Sorry for the multiple cmts (limited number of characters per cmt). Thats all I get when I run the `iotedge logs Modbus`. I only receive the updates here when I change the module twin for example. Nothing else...

Comment: I can't see anything from the log extracts. You could open a GitHub issue on the modbus module repository.

Comment: Thank you René for your answer. I did already but nobody answering there. However, I could get results using python libraries and other docker images... I think the problem is coming from the Modbus module itself.